# Hide Product without Disabling or putting product out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have a product that I want to hide on the front-end but if you have the direct URL I want the product to be accessible and have stock.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking of wrapping an `IF` statement around the product content in category grid etc and checking if the product has a custom attribute that says hidden. Is this a crazy way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the product from all categories and make the visibility field `Catalog`. This will remove it from search results also.
And you will still have access to it if you have the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I would just not include that product in the category. If you don't include it in your category then that product will not appear there.

If you want to do it in the code, then your way to do it seems the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The product will still show when a user searches for it. No worries will do what I've mentioned. :)

Comment: @MikeTimTurner to exclude it from search you can select Catalog in visibility attribute, rather than Catalog and search.